# Steam CMD on ARM based Linux(CentOS)

Tags: linux, centos, steam

Is there way to install Steam CMD on my ARM based Linux?
I have CentOS(aarch64) and I want to install Steam CMD, but I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. There is only one Linux version of SteamCMD: 32-bit i686.

Of course, QEMU User Mode Emulation is still theoretically an option to run this binary. There is little point in doing so, of course, because while you may be able to download games, you’ll very likely run into problems running them. You’ll probably have to manage an entire `chroot` of x86 and x86-64 binaries.

Also keep in mind that most ARM CPUs available to end-users are not very powerful.